# `io.Copy` file size different from original

Tags: go

I am dealing with multipart/form-data file upload and my backend uses Go `io.Copy` to copy the form data to local file.

```
func SaveFileHandler() error {
    ...

    file := form.File["file_uploaded"] // file uploaded in form
    src, _ := file.Open()

    // here the original file size is 35540353 in my case, 
    // which is a video/mp4 file
    fmt.Println(file.Size) 

    // create a local file with same filename
    dst, _ := os.Create(file.Filename)

    // save it
    _, err = io.Copy(dst, src)

    // err is nil
    fmt.Println(err) 

    stat, _ := dst.Stat()
    // then the local file size differs from the original updated one. Why?
    // local file size becomes 35537281 (original one is 35540353)
    fmt.Println(stat.Size()) 
    // meanwhile I can't open the local video/mp4 file, 
    // which seems to be broken due to losing data from `io.Copy`

    ...
```

How can it be? Is there any max buffer size for `io.Copy`? Or does file mime type matter in this case?
I tried with png and txt file and both worked as expected.

The Go version is `go1.12.6 linux/amd64`

Comment: Are there any errors? Are you closing the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not too much information in your question, but from what you've said, I bet the data isn't being flushed to the file completely before you call `dst.Stat()`.  You could close the file first to ensure that the data is fully flushed:

```
func SaveFileHandler() error {
    ...

    // create a local file with same filename
    dst, _ := os.Create(file.Filename)

    // save it
    _, err = io.Copy(dst, src)

    // Close the file
    dst.Close()

    // err is nil
    fmt.Println(err) 

    stat, _ := dst.Stat()    
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks @agillgilla! That's the point. I called stat.Size() before Flushing the file. Thank you for great answer!

Comment: Sure. Actually I was using a mimetype detect package to read the source file before io.Copy. For some reason the package causes the original file broken. So it shouldn't be io.Copy issue. Thank you!